# Regarding SSL setSessionTimeout

Tags: java, ssl

I have created a SSL session. I want to invalidate the session whenever it exceeds the timeout value. My question is shall I need to add separate code for checking the session time to invalidate the session page or will this function automatically take care of this?

```
socket.startHandshake();
sess= socket.getSession()
socket.setSessionTimeout(120);
```

To sets the sessiontimeout

```
setsessiontimeout()
```

Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.

Comment: Are you talking about the SSL session or the servlet session?

Comment: There is no such API as SSLSocket.setSessionTimeout(), as appears in your code. What is a 'session page'? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you know what an SSL session or its timeout really are. I think you are really talking about the servlet session identified by JSESSIONID. Its timeout value is configured in web.xml. The servlet container will invalidate the session automatically when it times out.

SSL sessions are used to reduce handshake overheads when multiple connections occur between the same two peers. Setting the timeout on an SSL session causes it to expire after the timeout, but that just means that the client has to create a new SSL session with a full handshake next time he connects (because a new connection cannot join an expired session). It doesn't mean for example that his existing connection gets invalidated, or that he gets logged out of the web application.

On the other hand if your question really is about `SSLSessionContext.setSessionTimeout()`, (a) yes it sets the SSL session timeout, just like it says in the Javadoc, and (b) I cannot understand why you are asking about other methods in JSSE to do the same thing.

Comment: i want to know that second time while resuming the connection after 10 mnts, the value of the timer which is set at the time of full handshake(30 mnts by setsessiontimeout()) will keep same as the original ie 30 mnts or the remaining 20mnts (second time we are not setting timer).

Comment: There is nothing in RFC 2246 to suggest that the timout is reset, and nothing in the Javadoc that says that it ever gets changed other than via `setSessionTimeout()`.

Comment: One more doubt regarding this. Usually where I can set the timeout? in server or in client? and when I can set this - after createSoket() and before startHandShake() or after startHandshake()

Comment: `SSLSessionContext.setSessionTimeout()`, in the server or the client. The lower timeout wins. You can call that any time you have an `SSLContext` to call `SSLContext.getClientSessionContext()` or `SSLContext.getServerSessionContext()` with.

Comment: Just for confirmation: According to my search, sessionTimeout in Apache Tomcat configuration and TLS session resumption timeout are different.  Am I right?

Comment: Is there any parameters available in tomcat to configure the session Resumption timeout

Comment: @user1345697 Correct, the Tomcat session timeout refers to the Servlet session, not the TLS/SSL session. I'm not aware of anything in Tomcat to configure the SSL session timeout but I could be wrong: take a good look at the Connector documentation.

Comment: Please let me know shall I use SSLSessionCacheTimeout  for the purpose of setting TLS session resumption time.